# Staircase numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

A staircase number is a positive integer **x** such that its **n**th digit (one indexed starting with the least significant digit) is equal to **x % (n + 1)**.  Thats a bit of a mouthful so lets look at an example.  Take **7211311**, if we take the modular residues of **7211311** on the range 2-8 we get the following:

```
7211311 % 2 = 1
7211311 % 3 = 1
7211311 % 4 = 3
7211311 % 5 = 1
7211311 % 6 = 1
7211311 % 7 = 2
7211311 % 8 = 7
```

These are the digits of **7211311**!  Thus **7211311** is a staircase number.

### Task

Write code that takes when given a positive number as input, will output two distinct values one if the number *is* a staircase number and the other if it is not.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) competition so your aim should be to minimize the number of bytes in your source code.

### Test Cases

Here are the first 13 staircase numbers:

```
1, 10, 20, 1101, 1121, 11311, 31101, 40210, 340210, 4620020, 5431101, 7211311, 12040210
```

Comment: Isn't `0` a staircase numbers? A lot of answers think so.

Comment: @Okx the task is just to distinguish positive staircase numbers from positive non-staircase numbers, so the behavior is undefined for 0 and negative numbers.

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, 55 <s>57</s> bytes

```
f m|let n#x=n==0||n`mod`10==m`mod`x&&div n 10#(x+1)=m#2
```

A different approach than the other Haskell solution.

*Thanks xnor for saving 2 bytes.*

Comment: You can use [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127594/20260) to shorten the `let` expression.

Comment: A different, shorter approach. Well done! +1

Comment: `n==0` → `n<1` saves a byte.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>25</s> <s>21</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
{it+₂;?↔%}ᶠ↔c?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzqzRPtRU5O1/aO2Kaq1D7ctANLJ9v//mxsZGhobGgIA)

First Brachylog submission :D <s>probably very ungolfed</s>...many thanks to Leaky Nun and Fatalize for encouragement and help to golf this from 25 all the way down to just 14. :) :)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

#### Code:

```
ā>%JRQ
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SKOdqldQ4P//JmZGBgZGBgA)

#### Explanation:

```
ā        # Get the range [1 .. len(input)]
 >       # Increment by 1
  %      # Vectorized modulo
   J     # Join the array into a single number
    RQ   # Reverse that number and check if it's equal to the original input
```

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript, <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @Shaggy and @ETHProductions

```
s=>[...s].some(d=>s%i++^d,i=~s.length)
```

This takes the number as a string and returns `false` if the number is a staircase number and `true` otherwise.

Example code snippet:

```js
f=
s=>[...s].some(d=>s%i++^d,i=~s.length)

function update() {
  o.innerText = f(document.getElementById("i").value)
}
```

```html
<input id="i" type="number">
<button onclick="update()">Test</button>
<p id="o">
```

Comment: You should be able to drop the `!` as the challenge doesn't explicitly specify that you must return `true` for true and `false` for false, simply that you must return 2 distinct values.

Comment: This is very well golfed, well done. I think you should be able to squeeze out two more bytes if you calculate `i` yourself: `s=>[...s].some(d=>s%i--^d,i=s.length+1)`

Comment: Actually, by exploiting the fact that `~x == -(x+1)` on integers and `x%-y == x%y`, I think you can get one more: `s=>[...s].some(d=>s%i++^d,i=~s.length)`

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=0:10**x>n or(`n%(x+2)`==`n`[~x])*f(n,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrRCsIgFAbg@57iv4l5nMX0cuBeJAKNsoR2HOKFY6xXt33X37KWT2LTWrBfPz@eHqyqHUY9SFknRsrC8VnU3pCz1rG7/eqdZBBH6zW1kDIiIiN7fr@EVjCaxhOw5MgF3bbjMmHbu@sxZ19EVAgiErU/)

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 60 bytes

Takes the number as an int

```
x n|s<-show n=reverse s==(rem n.(+1)<$>[1..length s]>>=show)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a string.

```
Ô¶¡%´J
```

2 bytes saved with help from [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions).

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1LahJbRK&input=IjcyMTEzMTEi)

```
Ô¶¡%´J     :Implicit input of string U
Ô          :Reverse
 ¶         :Test for equality with 
  ¡        :Map U
   %       :  Modulo
    ´J     :  J (initially -1) prefix decremented
```

Comment: Gosh darn `(Y+2`, I feel like that could be at least 1 byte shorter...

Comment: ...and it can: `¥£%´JÃw` :-) (works because `x%y == x%-y` in JS)

Comment: Aha, yes, was trying a few different things to get that calculation down to 2 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 60 bytes

```
FromDigits@Reverse@Mod[#,Range@Length@IntegerDigits@#+1]==#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfrSg/1yUzPbOk2CEotSy1qDjVwTc/JVpZJygxLz3VwSc1L70kw8EzryQ1PbUIqlBZ2zDW1lZZ7X9AUWZeiYKDQpqCg6GRgYmBkaHBfwA)

@alephalpha golfed it to 48

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
FromDigits@Reverse@Mod[#,Range[2,Log10@#+2]]==#&
```

next one is 24120020

Answer (score 4):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 6 bytes

```
ᛖ
```

Explanation:

```
         Get the length of the input, then create an exclusive range
 ᛖ        Add 2 to each element
         Modulus
          Reverse
          Join
         Check for equality
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCcsfzp72Ye7UFiBzNRAv/jB3yp7//w0NAA)

Comment: @Thehx Regarding your edit, Neim uses a custom encoding: [this one](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
DJ‘⁸%⁼Ṛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/F61HDjEeNO1QfNe55uHPW////zY0MDY0NDQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx).

```
qsjk_m%QhdSl`
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qsjk_m%25QhdSl%60&input=7211311&debug=0)

**Explanation**

```
             QQ    # Implicit input
          Sl`Q     # Generate [1, len(str(Q))]
     m%Qhd         # For digit d in above range, perform Q % (d + 1)
 sjk_              # Reverse, then convert to number
q             Q    # Test equality with input
```

**Alternate solution**, still 13 bytes (thanks to [karlkastor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56557/karlkastor))

```
qi_.e%Q+2k`QT
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qi_.e%25Q%2B2k%60QT&input=7211311&debug=0) That's essentially the same as the first solution, excepted that it uses `i` to convert from array of numbers to a number, and that the range is generated differently.

Comment: You can replace `ss\`M_` with `jk_` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Okx I need it because `j` outputs a string whereas I need a number to compare with the input (which is a number).

Comment: Another 13 byte solution would be: `qi_.e%Q+2k\`QT` using enumerated map (`.e`) instead of map. And converting the remainders to a base 10 int from the list instead of using join.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda x:all(`x%(i+2)`==`x`[~i]for i in range(len(`x`)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfll@kkKmQmaeQlplTklqkofE/JzE3KSVRocIqMSdHI6FCVSNT20gzwdY2oSIhui4zFq6hKDEvPVUjJzUPqChBU1Pzv6YOVMzQAAw0Na24FICgoCgzr0Qh8/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 43 bytes

```php
for(;$r<$a=$argn;)$r=$a%~++$i.$r;echo$r>$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmerZG5kaGhsaKhk/T8tv0jDWqXIRiXRFixnralSBGSp1mlrq2TqqRRZpyZn5KsU2akkWv//DwA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

prints 1 for true and nothing for false

```php
for(;$r<$a=$argn;)$r=$a%~++$i.$r;echo$r==$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmerZG5kaGhsaKhk/T8tv0jDWqXIRiXRFixnralSBGSp1mlrq2TqqRRZpyZn5AOFgGLW//8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 32 bytes

```
{$_ eq[~] $_ «%«(1+.comb...2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiVeIbUwui5WAcg4tFr10GoNQ2295PzcJD09PSPN2v/WCsWJlQrpRakFQA06CoZ6eoZGBgYG/wE)

- `.comb` is the number of characters in the string representation of the input argument `$_` (that is, the number of digits).
- `1 + .comb ... 2` is the sequence of numbers from one greater than the number of digits down to 2.
- `«%«` is the modulus hyperoperator that gives the remainder when `$_`, the input argument on its left, is divided by each of the elements of the sequence on its right: `$_ % 2, $_ % 3, ...`.
- `[~]` concatenates those digits into a new number, which is compared with the input argument using the string equality operator `eq`.

Answer (score 2):

## C++,104 bytes

1) original version:

```cpp
int main(){int N,T,R=1;cin>>N;T=N;for(int i=1;i<=log10(N)+1;i++){if(N%(i+1)!=T%10){R=0;}T/=10;}cout<<R;}
```

2) in a readable form:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int N, T, R = 1;

    cin >> N;
    T = N;

    for (int i = 1; i <= log10(N) + 1; i++)
    {
        if (N % (i + 1) != T % 10)
        {
            R = 0;
        }

        T /= 10;
    }

    cout << R;
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##RYtNDoMgGET3noKmMYFgU1nzcwQWhgsQRPslBYzgynh2iquu5s2bjNu21@pcfUJ032P2SEDKZfc2qO7vXLDlo7ojQ1xRtMHnzTqPcpl5hVhQsBAxOW/UgxkmybiDqJTmRmq@pB3fEzQNQn7TykasCW2N0vZasO4xUEYe0vRsJOckR36Zt2QtXDqKEBO/amU/)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 19 bytes

```apl
{⍵=10⊥⌽⍵|⍨1↓⍳1+≢⍕⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR71ZbQ4NHXUsf9ewFsmse9a4wfNQ2@VHvZkPtR52LHvVOBYrW/k971DbhUW/fo67mR71rHvVuObTe@FHbxEd9U4ODnIFkiIdn8P80BTOuNAVzI0NDY0NDAA)

Creates two lists of digits and check if they are equal.

### Explanation

```apl
{⍵=10⊥⌽⍵|⍨1↓⍳1+≢⍕⍵} ⍵ → input
               ≢⍕⍵  length of ⍵ as a string
             1+     +1
            ⍳       range from 1 to that
          1↓        Drop first element 
       ⍵|⍨          ⍵ mod each element in range
      ⌽             reversed
   10⊥              converted from base 10
 ⍵=                 equals the input?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 42 bytes

```
n->Vecrev(s=digits(n))==[n%d|d<-[2..#s+1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y4sNbkotUyj2DYlMz2zpFgjT1PT1jY6TzWlJsVGN9pIT0@5WNswNvZ/Wn6RRh5Qj6GOgqGBgY5CQVFmXglQRElB1w5IpIE0av4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66 60 58</s> 57 bytes

- Thanks to @Leaky nun for 6 bytes: remove unneeded `x and` (shouldnot check for 0)
- Thanks to @Einkorn Enchanter for 1 byte: use of `enumerate`

```python
lambda x:all(a==`x%(i+2)`for i,a in enumerate(`x`[::-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrRCsIwDADf/Yq8CAkquD0G@iUqNGKrgS4bpUL9@sztng7ull/7zDZ6DncvMj1fAp2lFJQQYj@inkaKea6gZwE1SPadUpWWMPZ4Y74MDyLfhy1XsXfC4bpDfADNkFGJYalq7W/uKw)

Comment: [Shorter if you enumerate](https://tio.run/##HYrRCsIwDADf/Yq8CAkquD0G@iUqNGKrgS4bpUL9@sztng7ull/7zDZ6DncvMj1fAp2lFJQQYj@inkaKea6gZwE1SPadUpWWMPZ4Y74MDyLfhy1XsXfC4bpDfADNkFGJYalq7W/uKw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thank you. And hey, I just realised you were wheat wizard.. :D

Comment: This is a very late comment, but `enumerate` can take a second argument "number to start counting from", so `x%i` and `enumerate(…,2)` saves two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>20</s> 15 bytes

```
⌊Ｅθ⁼ιＩ﹪Ｉθ⁻⁺¹Ｌθκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBDkAwEATQX@lxJZVocHIUNxK/sEForFZV/f7aMIfJJG@mDa/JIzGPl3U3DNbZIx0w4AlBqy4kpAhWqxajqJ8Tefh2yLSSd4owkpTRql/cem8CInv2p2Guq9KYwnD@cB7pBQ) Outputs `-` for a staircase number, nothing otherwise. Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, <strike>156</strike> <strike>149</strike> bytes

```
interface B{static void main(String[]s){String f="";for(int i=1;i<=s[0].length();)f=new Long(s[0])%++i+f;System.out.print(f.equals(s[0]));}}
```

Ungolfed :

```
interface B {
    static void main(String[] s) {
        String f = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= s[0].length();)
            f = new Long(s[0]) % ++i + f;
        System.out.print(f.equals(s[0]));
    }
}
```

[Try it Online !](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoIwFEV/pSExaUNsrA4OtYubMyNhaOAVi9Bi@8AYwrdXjG4nueeeTs9670dwXfNIyTqEYHQN5LpE1GhrMnvbkEFbRwsM1rVlFdnyQ2JUlknjA91@xCoh7UXF8lDxHlyLd8okM4o6eJHbFm4h0O/K2I7muWW5kcU7IgzcT8jHrYi9o4bDc9J9/KtyXVNK56MQJyE@)

**UPDATE :**
*-7 bytes* : removed useless `{}` and replaced `Integer.parseInt(...)` by `new Integer(...)`
*-9 bytes* : thanks to Kevin Cruijssen, removed a bunch of useless `()`, used `Long` instead of `Integer` and `print` instead of `println`. Thanks Kévin !

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me. Btw, some small things to golf: `new Integer` can be `new Long` (-3 bytes); `println` can be `print` (-2 bytes); and you can remove the parenthesis surrounding `new Long(s[0])%i+f;` (-4 bytes).

Comment: Really nice ! Thanks, i'll update this !

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3: 63 Bytes

```
lambda m:all(int(x)==m%(n+2)for n,x in enumerate(str(m)[::-1]))
```

If I could count the number of times I wished 'enumerate' were shorter...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEADAr@wl2KWCrJvgS6KDkVHgrqIG9Xqr4xwmPuUIMtWajbe8bhZYW@/xlII3GcMNSjsS7CGBdDecAk4udskWh7kkZJq17tVCVGP6V0alBvXxBQ)

Comment: Yep, and I just realized its exactly the same as the answer @officialaimm gave...  Should I remove?

Comment: Theirs is in python 2 and you came up with it independently so I would leave it.

Comment: Can save two bytes by starting your enumeration at 2 and rearranging the logical: `lambda m:all(m%n==int(x)for n,x in enumerate(str(m)[::-1],2))`

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 60 bytes

```java
n->{int m=2,r=0,t=1;for(;n>=t;t*=10)r+=n%m++*t;return r==n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNa9tAEL37VwwBgxQpYld2Uoi6gR566CGh4GPIYS2v03WtkZgdpRij3@6OPoJC2oWd2Z2PN@/Nwb7Zm7pxeNj9vjTt9uhLKI82BHi0HuG8AJiigS2Le6v9DirJRRsmj6/PL2DpNcRDKcBB8LKW/THbt1iyrzH7gfyT3M6Xlh00YC5483D2yFCZPCWjUja62NcUFfhguOBro1VMicFllSTXXJDjlhDIGCy6CwynWAzTBEXmCzNPpQ3uqa22jgIYQPdnTJ51ClqlkMvVWvU/nQ92pcWtxtha5X3RavLru1ypvuN2PRV8yacGnauhqCsGAkIbol4L3v9D430lAJtTYFdldctZIzvjfXS11CrcwzIs8SoFTKHJ2AWOMI5H4O4TvKwIEL6Klv7IO0lmfL@HaF78NyJ7CtnWo6XTxlkqf0WfucnMWNDUjDGizDQ@JP4r4DtRTaJAdIwaJuIz@Xff227RXf4C)

A non-string version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

```hs
f n=foldr(\(k,_)a->10*a+mod n k)0(zip[2..]$show n)==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcHBCoMwDADQX8nBQ7vNorvt0P2IkxHUzNKYllYY@PFmsPdWrHFhViUQT4nnYl4m3t4W22ffXfC6pRkEou3MEfJwd25s6pq@INZ70Q2DgIdcguzQAAXelwIEQ@/c42/UcyLGT9V2yvkH)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 61 bytes

```
lambda x:[`x%(n+2)`for n in range(len(`x`))][::-1]==list(`x`)
```

Comment: Nope, your new golf is a byte shorter. :)

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 34 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{s~raze($)x mod'2+(|)(!)(#)s:($)x}
```

**Example:**

```
q){s~raze($)x mod'2+(|)(!)(#)s:($)x}7211311 / this is a staircase number (true)
1b
q){s~raze($)x mod'2+(|)(!)(#)s:($)x}7211312 / this is not (false)
0b
q)t(&){s~raze($)x mod'2+(|)(!)(#)s:($)x}each t:1 + til 1000000 / up to a million
1 10 20 1101 1121 11311 31101 40210 340210
```

**Explanation:**

Cast the input number to a string, count from 0..length of string, add 2 to all, reverse it and feed each number into `mod` along with the original input. Cast the result of the mod to a string and reduce the list, check if it is equal to the string of the input number:

```
{s~raze string x mod'2 + reverse til count s:string x} / ungolfed solution
{                                                    } / lambda function
                                           s:string x  / convert input to string, save as s
                                     count             / return length of this string
                                 til                   / like python's range() function
                         reverse                       / reverses the list
                     2 +                               / adds two to each element in the list
               x mod'                                  / ' is each both, so feeds x, and each element of the list to modulo function
        string                                         / converts output list to string list ("7";"2";"1"..etc)
   raze                                                / reduce list ("721...")
 s~                                                    / is s equal to this reduced list, returns boolean
```

**Notes:**

Most of the solution is for generating the `2,3,4..` list, I have another solution that does less stuff, but winds up being 37 bytes after golfing:

```
{s~x mod'reverse 2 + til count s:("J"$) each string x} / ungolfed
{s~x mod'(|)2+til(#)s:("J"$)each($)x}                  / golfed
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 75 bytes

```
#(=(sort %)(sort(map(fn[i c](char(+(mod(Integer. %)(+ i 2))48)))(range)%)))
```

Input is a string, using `map` and the trailing `%` ended up being shorter than `for[i(range(count %))]` approach.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 62 bytes

`f x=and$zipWith(==)(reverse$show x)$map(head.show.mod x)[2..]`

Instead of reversing the (infinite) list of moduli, it truncates the list by zipping it with the reversed string-respresentation of the integral x, which it then ensures is equal element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 41 bytes

39 bytes of code + 2 flags `-pa`

```perl
map{$\||=$_!=$F[0]%++$n}0,reverse/./g}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJaamxlYlXtFWxS3aIFZVW1slr9ZApyi1LLWoOFVfTz@9tvr/f3MjQ0NjQ8N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWJAIA)

Outputs nothing (undef) for staircase numbers, 1 for anything else

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt#L332), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
mækî)%Ñ
```

Input as a string.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/38LLsw@s0VQ9P/P9fyVCJS8nQAEgYgQhDQwOwgKERhDI2BNHGUGETAyOwUmMYw8TMyMAArNHUBKbI3AimzdDIAKbQCKQEREOsM4CQYCMMDeG0IdgZED0A)

**Explanation:**

```python
m        # Map over each character of the (implicit) input-string,
 æ       # using the following four characters as inner code-block:
         #  (implicitly push the current character of the map)
  k      #  Push the input as an integer
   î     #  Push the 1-based map-index
    )    #  Increase it by 1
     %   #  Take the input-integer modulo (1-based) index+1
         # After the map, the digits are implicitly joined together to a string
      Ñ  # Check that this string is a palindrome
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 42 bytes

```arturo
$[n][1every? reverse digits n'x->x=n%<=1+]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Ng8O9j)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes

```
==.,,;`@~$%_+$~\@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWG21t9XR0rBMc6lRU47VV6mIcIOJQ6QU3Uw25DA24jAy4DA0NgExDIxBhbGjIZQwWMDEwAkobQygTMyMDA6BSUxOIpLkRRKmhkQFEgRFQL1ALkASLGpuAlBgBlUBsAwA)

```
==.,,;`@~$%_+$~\@
==                Equal
  .                map
   ,                range
    ,                length
     ;                A :=
      `@~              decimal digits
         $              input
          %         mod
           _         input
            +        add
             $        it
              ~       1
               \   reverse
                @   A
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
i,j,k;f(n){for(i=j=k=1;++j,i<n;i*=10)k=n/i%10^n%j?0:k;return k;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##bY/RCoJAEEXf/YpBEHbTave1celHIjB1Y1wcY9VexG83C82HOi9z4V4OTL6/5/k0UVIlDq1gOdjGCzKVcUZjHFcJpYy0M1pJZ/hIkVZXjqqzOjn0Zdd7BofjRNxBnRGLZ0OFDIYAFmYdiHdLYEDjfFLQ6gNCHJOEbbtCFoQVJP91Kw8/S60IowKohQzaLiOfZ20J3Ne30h8uHCZAEn8MY7Clb1xeURiM0ws)

Explanation:

```c
i,j,k;
f(n)
{
    // i and k are 1, j is 2 since it's incremented before the first check for
    // i < n (and at the end of every loop). i is multiplied by 10 at the end
    // of each iteration.
    for(i=j=k=1;++j,i<n;i*=10)
        // If digit i doesn't equal n modulo j, set k to 0.
        k=n/i%10^n%j?
            0
        :
            k;
    
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `k*=n/i%10==n%j` instead of `k=n/i%10^n%j?0:k`